# Changing script to send non-duplicate values to a new sheet instead of duplicate values

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a script that iterates through 2 spreadsheets, finds duplicate values in column A, then appends the row of these duplicate values to another sheet.

I actually want this script to do a similar thing, but append the rows that are NOT duplicates instead of the ones that are.  How can I alter it so that it sends the non duplicates to the "New Students" sheet"?  I tried changing the == to !==.  But that sends the whole list.  I have been searching around for a while and I know it's probably an easy fix.
Thanks so much!
Brandon

```
function compareandupdate() { 
  var s1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXXXXX-vvxyewdki0J9tGqJl9_f-wZE0zOboQRIscLAA").getSheetByName('Updated Student List');
  var s2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXXXXX-yB9Xm1J5RKWS7NF23vD-NTUeIgspbctj3leW4").getSheetByName('Master Student List');
  var s3 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXXXXX-yB9Xm1J5RKWS7NF23vD-NTUeIgspbctj3leW4").getSheetByName('New Students');

  var values1 = s1.getDataRange().getValues();
  var values2 = s2.getDataRange().getValues();
  var resultArray = [];

for(var n=0; n < values1.length ; n++){
    var keep = false;
    for(var p=0; p < values2.length ; p++){
      Logger.log(values1[n][0]+' =? '+values2[p][0]);
      if( values1[n][0] == values2[p][0]){
        resultArray.push(values1[n]);
        Logger.log('true');
        break ;// remove this if values are not unique and you want to keep all occurrences...
      }
    }
  }  
  s3.getRange(+1,1,resultArray.length,resultArray[0].length).setValues(resultArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you prefer to keep your existing structure *(which I think I wrote some time ago ;-) and btw has an unnecessary variable (keep)!)* you can use this modified version of your code :

```
function compareAndUpdate() { 
  var s1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXXXXX-vvxyewdki0J9tGqJl9_f-wZE0zOboQRIscLAA").getSheetByName('Updated Student List');
  var s2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXXXXX-yB9Xm1J5RKWS7NF23vD-NTUeIgspbctj3leW4").getSheetByName('Master Student List');
  var s3 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXXXXX-yB9Xm1J5RKWS7NF23vD-NTUeIgspbctj3leW4").getSheetByName('New Students');

//  var definition for easier testing purpose  
//  var s1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
//  var s2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[1];
//  var s3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[2];

  var values1 = s1.getDataRange().getValues();
  var values2 = s2.getDataRange().getValues();
  var resultArray = [];

  for(var n=0; n < values1.length ; n++){
    var keep = true;
    for(var p=0; p < values2.length ; p++){
      Logger.log(values1[n][0]+' =? '+values2[p][0]);
      if( values1[n][0] == values2[p][0]){
        keep = false;// if same value in first column in s2 then don't keep (you can modify this condition to your needs, extend to whole row or other columns for example )
        break;
      }
    }
    if(keep){
      resultArray.push(values1[n]);// keep only values from s1 that are not in s2
    }  
  }
  s3.getRange(+1,1,resultArray.length,resultArray[0].length).setValues(resultArray);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, works great!  I learn so much from your scripts (as you can tell) :-)  I really appreciate all of the time you take to help others on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
function contains(array, entry) {
  for(var p=0; p < array.length ; p++){
    if(array[p][0] === entry){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

for(var n=0; n < values1.length ; n++) {
  if(!contains(values2, values1[n][0])) {
    resultArray.push(values1[n]);
  }
}
```